How does tagging for access control in AWS Systems Manager work with the delegated administrator?
OpsCenter supports access control through tagging. Users can restrict access to OpsItems based on specific tags, allowing for more granular control over who can view or manage incidents based on their assigned roles or responsibilities.
How does tagging for access control in AWS Systems Manager work with the delegated administrator?
